# I would throw away

Tags: grammar

If you give me that hat, I think, I would throw it away.

Does this sound correct?

Do you need any context for this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is not correct; the tenses don't agree.

> If you give me that hat, I will throw it away.
>
> If you *gave* me (or *were to give* me) that hat, I would throw it away.

Comment: "Actions have consequences". As Rory explains to Nick the Greek in Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels - *If you hold back anything, I'll kill you. If you bend the truth, or I think you're bending the truth, I'll kill you. If you forget anything, I'll kill you. In fact, you're gonna have to work very hard to stay alive, Nick.* But it wouldn't have the same "threatening immediacy" if he'd said *If you **were to** forget anything...*

Answer (score 2):

"If you give me that hat, I think, I would throw it away." This is okay, because you could be saying what someone might do at the present time ("If you give me that hat,) as well as expressing what you think you would do with the hat at a later/future time (I think I would throw it away.") [I would suggest leaving out the second comma.]  **"If you give me that hat, I think I would throw it away."**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion; can you quote and link to sources that support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can say either give or gave, along with I would or I will. Both are correct, despite tense, in this case.

Comment: Well, if my answer is considered my opinion, this is because I have learned, speak and write in English, my native language. I have no reference or source to cite... And if I did, would I have to ask that source for their source, meaning in certain circumstances and answers, is it possible that there is no source beyond or before self?